# How can I send SMS from Ubuntu to cell phones?

Tags: text, sms

I'm tired of paying for my cell phone. It's just a small glorified computer and anyone wanting to contact me can contact me when I'm home.

I would, however, be willing to pay small fee for the ability to use sms text messaging using my internet on my computer.

Is this possible in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

SMS from Ubuntu is possible. This is not specific to the OS. The support for SMS comes from applications. I know of at least two application that makes SMS from Ubuntu possible:

[Skype for Linux supports SMS](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12044/how-do-i-send-sms-text-messages-from-skype-for-linux) for a fee.

**To send a text to one of your contacts**

1. In Skype, find the person you want to text and click on them.
2. Right-click the contact, select **Send SMS** and then select the number you wish to text.

[image]

[Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice) has the capability to SMS from web browser, both send and receive (to phones in the US only?). So far it's free. Thanks tufkab for mentioning this in the comments.

Google Chat also allowed SMS from the web browser. Now that chat has been moved to Google Hangout, this feature is gone. It may come back in the future.

Hope this helps

Comment: Google Voice has text from web browser, both send and receive. https://www.google.com/voice  So far it's been free.

Comment: Thanks @tufkab. I forgot about the web interface of Google Voice. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can send sms from Skype which is available for Ubuntu (though I'm not 100% sure the Linux client supports sms messages). http://www.skype.com/en/features/sms/ for more information on that.

Also, a Google search of "sms online" brought up several websites that provide sms sending services. You'll likely have to try a few before you find one that works the way you want it to.